# How to delete specific element in 3D numpy array

Tags: python, list, numpy

I'm trying to analyze biological datas and I have a list of arrays as follows :

```
[[['ENSMUSG00000000001' '-0.072141867' '0.153569137']
  ['ENSMUSG00000000028' '-0.031985346' '0.537383098']
  ['ENSMUSG00000000037' '0.046097573' '0.727492292']]

 [['ENSMUSG00000000001' '0.422529239' '4.86E-24']
  ['ENSMUSG00000000028' '-0.036262661' '0.393367015']
  ['ENSMUSG00000000037' '0.070899297' '0.427056034']]

 [['ENSMUSG00000000001' '0.117877802' '0.000480518']
  ['ENSMUSG00000000028' '0.122150713' '0.000368726']
  ['ENSMUSG00000000037' '0.009156006' '0.912776746']
  ['ENSMUSG00000110411' '-1.67014277' '7.92E-05']
  ['ENSMUSG00000110415' '-0.103612996' '0.606599177']
  ['ENSMUSG00000110424' '0.357829407' '0.053448692']]]
```

and i would like to delete few of the smallest lists To have for example for a list of index to delete as

```
[(0,1),(1,2),(2,3)]
```

and i would like to get :

```
[[['ENSMUSG00000000001' '-0.072141867' '0.153569137']
  ['ENSMUSG00000000037' '0.046097573' '0.727492292']]

 [['ENSMUSG00000000001' '0.422529239' '4.86E-24']
  ['ENSMUSG00000000028' '-0.036262661' '0.393367015']]

 [['ENSMUSG00000000001' '0.117877802' '0.000480518']
  ['ENSMUSG00000000028' '0.122150713' '0.000368726']
  ['ENSMUSG00000000037' '0.009156006' '0.912776746']
  ['ENSMUSG00000110415' '-0.103612996' '0.606599177']
  ['ENSMUSG00000110424' '0.357829407' '0.053448692']]]
```

So I tried several solutions with or without numpy but none of them is working

The idea i'm focused on would be something like this (where tot is my full array and delindex the positions of the elements i want to get rid of)

```
for e in delindex[::-1]:
    tot=np.delete(tot,e[1],e[0])
```

But i always get the error :

```
IndexError: index 12263 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 3
```

As you noticed, my array is very big so i can't use iterative loops on it

Comment: You have a list of arrays that differ in size.  You have to iterate on that list and/or the tuples that index the list.

Comment: What is the `dtype` and `shape` of `tot`?

Comment: I finally didn't used numpy for this and the solution appears to be quite simple : ``` for x,y in delindex[::-1]:
  del tot[x][y]```

Answer (score 0):

Use `del`:

```
d = [(0,1),(1,2),(2,3)]

for x, y in d:
    del lst[x][y]
```

where `lst` is your original list of lists.

Comment: I just tried but get the error ```ValueError: cannot delete array elements```, got an idea to force the deletion or do you advise me to avoid numpy before deletion ? When i do i get the error ```IndexError: list assignment index out of range```

Comment: What is the output of `lst[0]` ?

Comment: I figured out i get this error, i simply had several elements to delete in each sublist, so i used ```d[::-1]``` instead of ```d```. The output of lst [0] would have been something like ``` [ ['ENSMUSG00000024617', '-0.427758884', '0.00095345'], ... , ['ENSMUSG00000024752', '0.314781186', '3.63E-13'] ]```